# Graph representation - display individuals by data property and group by type

Tags: plugins, graph, protege

I currently use OntoGraf 1.0.3 (via "Class views"/"OntoGraf") to display a small ontology created in Protege 5 beta-17 as a graph; not out of choice but because it is the first tool I found.

My chosen display mode is "Horizontal Directed". Unfortunately, within a layer the order of items appears to be random; it would help clarity if they could be grouped by their type. 
***Is this possible and how?***

Furthermore, nodes in the graph are displayed by their URI. All individuals have a data property "Name" however, and I would like those to be labelled with that property instead of their URI. 
***Is this possible and how?***

---

***Bonus question:***
When displaying the whole ontology, layers of the tree are strictly arranged based on relation jumps; I would like to push individuals below the deepest class layer.

To elaborate, this is how it looks like:

```
  C
  |\
  C I <- same layer, no correlation
 /| |
I C I <- same layer, no correlation
```

This is how I would like it:

```
  C
  |\
  C \
 /|  |
| C  |
I    I  <- same layer, same level of abstraction
     |
     I
```

---

If there is a better solution to produce a graphical tree with such characteristics, I will gladly accept that instead.